# How to know in advance from reflection if the reflective access to Java class instance will be illegal or not

Tags: java, reflection

We use utility class which is traversing the content of any object and performs the "flattening" of the object fields or result of the getter calls into maps. This is executed  until some level recursively.
It is a great help for logging and searching of problems in more complex structures, where the "toString" methods do not deliver anything reasonable or just not enough information.

It works well, but of course sometimes until Java 9 and above the warning

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

can occur in the case the instance is of the class from another module, not allowed to be accessed. So here is my question:

Is there in the Java reflection facility some way how to simply get the information if the access is not allowed or allowed in advance, to have the possibility to prevent generally such calls which will/would end by this error/warning?

Answer (score 3):

There is no method to query the outcome before trying. But you can replace `setAccessible(true)` with [`trySetAccessible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#trySetAccessible()) to check whether the operation is possible while trying.

For example:

```java
public class AccessTest {
    private String test = "hello";
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      test(new AccessTest(), "test");
      test(new ArrayList<>(), "modCount");
    }
  
    private static void test(Object obj, String fieldName) {
        for(Class<?> cl = obj.getClass(); cl != null; cl = cl.getSuperclass()) try{
            Field f = cl.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            System.out.println(f +
                (f.trySetAccessible()? " = " + f.get(obj): "  inaccessible"));
            return;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException ex) {}
        catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        System.out.println(fieldName + " not found in " + obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

Before Java 16, you have to run the program with the option `--illegal-access=deny` to replace the warning with an actual rejection. With Java 16, this is the default. Starting with Java 17, illegal access will always be denied.

In an environment rejecting the access, the example program will print

```
private java.lang.String AccessTest.test = hello
protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount  inaccessible
```